# What maps have Gunship and Cruise Missile available for Commander?

Tags: battlefield-4

I cannot find a list of what is available to the commanders on each map anywhere online, and figure this might be very interesting for the people who are looking to get the gunship/cruise missile ribbons.

Comment: It might be better to post the ones you know so far as an answer and make it a community wiki, to separate the question from the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are all CQ/CQ large maps.

Cruise missile

- Flood Zone
- Hainan Resort
- Siege of Shanghai
- Zavod 311
- Guilin Peaks
- Lumphini Garden
- Propaganda
- Giants of Karelia
- Hammerhead
- Operation Whiteout
- Hangar 21
- Zavod Graveyard Shift
- Dragon Valley

Gunship

- Dawnbreaker
- Golmud Railway
- Lancang Dam
- Paracel Storm
- Rogue Transmission
- Operation Firestorm 2014
- Caspian Border 2014
- Gulf of Oman 2014
- Wave Breaker
- Nansha Strike

Some are still missing, but these should be correct. Usually, either you have Cruise missiles or you have the gunship, not both. Gunships are in general in large, very open maps while Cruise missiles are in almost every other  map where you can't find gunships (bar Locker and Metro iirc). I should check the Naval Strike maps but I'm pretty sure they all have the Gunship somewhere.

Comment: Whilst possibly true at the time, Operation Firestorm now has **both** Cruise Missiles and Gunship.  A win for commanders :)

Answer (score 4):

These are the ones I know so far:

- Cruise Missile

  - Siege of Shanghai
  - Zavod 311
  - Hainan Resort
    -Lancang Dam
- Gunship:

  - Golmud Railway
  - Paracel Storm
  - Op. Firestorm 2014 CQ
  - Caspian Border 2014 CQ
  - Dawnbreaker CQ
  - Lancang Dam CQ
  - Rogue Transmission CQ
  - Gulf of Oman 2014 CQ
- Neither:

  - Operation Locker

I will try to edit when I find more.

Comment: You may also want to note that this is for CQ. I think Obliteration only has cruise missiles, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @turbo I know Flood Zone has Cruise Missile for Obliteration.

Comment: Operation Locker has the annoying "ability" to make dropped quad bikes and resupply packages float in midair and never come down even when they're outside

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a gunship on Lancang Dam.
And I *think* that I've seen a gunship on Op. Firestorm 2014.